# Oracle text: strange behaviour of score function

Tags: oracle, oracle-text

I've got a strange behaviour on a German surname "Warsoenke".

Check this out:

```
create table test_warsoe
as
select 'Mister Warsoenke ABC-12' name
from dual;

create index test_warsoe_index on test_warsoe(name) indextype is ctxsys.context;

select name,
       score(1) as rating_warsoe,
       score(2) as rating_warsoen
from test_warsoe
where contains(name,'definescore(Warsoe%,occurrence)',1) > 0
   or contains(name,'definescore(Warsoen%,occurrence)',2) > 0;
```

The output is:

```
Mister Warsoenke ABC-12  |  2  |  1
```

I cannot figure out why? If I type "Warsoe" or "War" it returns score 2. If I type "Warsoen" it works like, as I understand, it should and returns 1.

If I do not use `definescore` it works in the same direction, just shows different numbers (27 and 13).

For other surnames it works perfectly and clear. But for this one...

I had a guess this is because of German database settings, e.g. "War so e..." but this idea is quite strange and still it is not clear why "Warsoen" works then.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I've found out much more surnames which are not working like the described above. And I still do not see any possible explanation of this...

Comment: can you please post your `NLS_LANG` value? I tried with your DDL and Query , I got it as 1 and 1 ..You can see in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d31f4/1)

Comment: NLS_LANGUAGE: GERMAN, DB version: 11.2.0.2.0. I see, it works in sqlfiddle but on my server it does not...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just if somebody has the same problem, the problem was in setting of DEFAULT_LEXER:

```
BASE_LETTER        | YES
ALTERNATE_SPELLING | GERMAN
```

That's what we received after investigation:

To change the behaviour, either one of the two parameters have to be changed, or the additional parameter OVERRIDE_BASE_LETTER has to be set to true (according to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cspell.htm#CCREF2215)).